# Does Smartctl require a file system to run a test, and is my drive toast?

Tags: hard-disk, smartctl

I have a brand new drive that I want to test before using.  Just installed it, did not format/partition, nor create a filesystem on it yet.  **First thing I did was check the smartctl stats, then start a captive long test**.

After waiting the required 12 hours, I notice the test was interrupted, and an error was logged.  I start the test two more times, and **an error is logged immediately each test is initiated**.  See the smartctl stats below:

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-150-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST8000NM017B-2TJ103
Serial Number:    WWZ2AFQF
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0e71315e1
Firmware Version: SN01
User Capacity:    8,001,563,222,016 bytes [8.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-4 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.3, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Jun 10 08:08:32 2023 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (  41) The self-test routine was interrupted
                                        by the host with a hard or soft reset.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (  567) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 702) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x70bd) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   100   100   044    Pre-fail  Always       -       9402
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       1
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   100   253   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       21867
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       17
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       1
 18 Unknown_Attribute       0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       12885098499
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   067   066   000    Old_age   Always       -       33 (Min/Max 24/34)
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       39
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   033   040   000    Old_age   Always       -       33 (0 24 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0 (137 91 0)
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       9402

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 3
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 3 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 17 hours (0 days + 17 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 51 00 00 00 00 00  Error: ABRT

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff      17:21:46.602  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  b0 d4 00 82 4f c2 00 00      17:20:45.112  SMART EXECUTE OFF-LINE IMMEDIATE
  b0 d0 01 00 4f c2 00 00      17:20:45.112  SMART READ DATA
  ec 00 01 00 00 00 00 00      17:20:45.105  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 01 00 00 00 00 00      17:20:45.104  IDENTIFY DEVICE
Error 2 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 17 hours (0 days + 17 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 51 00 00 00 00 00  Error: ABRT

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff      17:15:48.188  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  b0 d4 00 82 4f c2 00 00      17:14:46.401  SMART EXECUTE OFF-LINE IMMEDIATE
  b0 d0 01 00 4f c2 00 00      17:14:46.400  SMART READ DATA
  ec 00 01 00 00 00 00 00      17:14:46.392  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 01 00 00 00 00 00      17:14:46.391  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 0 hours (0 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 51 00 00 00 00 00  Error: ABRT

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff      00:08:36.002  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  b0 d4 00 82 4f c2 00 00      00:07:34.853  SMART EXECUTE OFF-LINE IMMEDIATE
  b0 d0 01 00 4f c2 00 00      00:07:34.814  SMART READ DATA
  ec 00 01 00 00 00 00 00      00:07:34.806  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 01 00 00 00 00 00      00:07:34.805  IDENTIFY DEVICE

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended captive    Interrupted (host reset)      90%        17         -
# 2  Extended captive    Interrupted (host reset)      90%        17         -
# 3  Extended captive    Interrupted (host reset)      90%         0         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Raw read/seek error rates are quite high as well, but I'm never sure about the format of smartctl, and if those values are just encoded...

Smartctl does not require a formatted drive/drive with a file system to run properly, correct?  This is an unexpected result?  If so, are there **any other tests I should run before I RMA**?  Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can at least try in non-captive mode instead. `Interrupted (host reset)` is not really likely to be due to a problematic drive.

Comment: @TomYan True.  I'm less concerned about the `Interrupted` test as I am about the 3 errors that got logged, which appeared to occur immediately after the test command was issued.  Good idea about the non-captive mode, though.  Just started a non-captive mode test to see what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. S.M.A.R.T. selt-tests are run inside the disk, there's no need for an OS. Run any LiveCD, `smartctl -t long /dev/sda`, wait as long as it says, check the result. The PC must be running during the entire duration of the test. You cannot put the PC to sleep either.
2. Your drive looks totally healthy, and such errors `Error 3 occurred at disk power-on lifetime` are usually benign. I've had drives with similar errors which are still in a perfect condition after using them for more than a decade. Please check if smartmontools 7.3 report this error as well. It might be specific only to the old release.

Still, if you want to RMA it, by all means do it. It's not a pleasant feeling having any SMART errors from the get go.

```
# 1  Extended captive    Interrupted (host reset)      90%        17
```

Means you didn't allow the test to complete. The full test `-t long` for your drive may take around 24 hours to complete.

I always run a long self-test for new drives. Brings me a little peace of mind.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  However, I'm not sure what I would have done to interrupt it.  Ran test in captive mode, disk wasn't mounted (didn't have a filesystem!), for the 1st test I just let it alone overnight.  Next two times, tests ended immediately.  Trying it now in non-captive mode, and it's running without immediate error, so we'll see what happens!

Comment: Captive mode is quite finicky - I've long stopped using it. I've had more drives not completing tests with it, than just simple offline mode.

Comment: Yeah, offline mode (non-captive mode) completed just fine!  Thanks for the advice!